# Can Azure Data factory publish data to Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We need the ADF to publish the data to a 3rd Party application exposing its REST API, can it be done via ADF or need we have a custom .Net code to do the data posting.

From the documentation it seems it can only retrieve the data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish data to a REST API from within ADF by using a [web activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity) (recommended) or using a [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity) (using .NET code).

If you want to publish the output of an activity, you can chain the web activity to the activity you want to send the result of. You can then in your web activity reference the output of the previous activity using a dynamic expression similar to this :

```
@string(activity('CopyFromBlobToBlob').output)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: can i push data in tune of 100k records a day to a 3rd party Rest API.. in small batches of 2K records in one go?

Comment: Yes you can do that. However it would be better if you use a custom activity or an Azure function activity to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This table shows which connectors are supported as source and sink. None of the web-based connectors is currently supported as sink. So no, you cannot do this with the built-in copy activity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats

Comment: In this document, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity it seems that an API call can be possible as an output of the data factory pipeline. If the source and sink are correct than what's limiting the Web Activity control flow?

Comment: Of course you can have an outbound calling activity anywhere in the pipeline. However, as described in the documentation, the payload that you can send does not have any data in it. Just information about datasets and linked services

Comment: What you are looking for seems to be a way to send data - that would be a copy activity.

Comment: Thanks what I am looking for is pushing data to 3rd party app in bulk 100k records a day